# Два textarea Django, CKeditor. Как убрать один?

Tags: django, ckeditor

Добрый вечер! Учусь встраивать wysiwyg редактор в свой проект, но столкнулся с одной проблемой: вместо 1 текстового поля, выкидывает 2. Прошу, помогите. Не парьтесь с объяснением - я пойму. Заранее благодарен[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4SyL.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем всё это? Просто

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    text = RichTextField()
    ...
```

и

```
<form ...>
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```